# Proving $(\overline{z})^n$ = $\overline{z^n}$ by induction

Tags: complex-numbers, induction

Prove that $(\overline{z})^n$ = $\overline{z^n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by induction.

Comment: First, prove (by writing down LHS and RHS and confirming that they're equal) that $\overline{ab}=\overline a\overline b$. Then you may be able to proceed. And you probably meant $\Bbb N$, instead of $\Bbb R$: induction on $\Bbb R$ is quite hard to figure out.

Comment: You're right, I mistyped. Made the correction now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RESULT:** If $z,w\in\Bbb C$ the $\overline{zw}=\overline{z}\cdot\overline{w}$

**Problem:** $(\overline{z})^n$ = $\overline{z^n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

**Proof:** (by induction) The result is trivial if $n=1$. Suppose the statement holds for $n=k$. Then
$$(\overline{z})^k =\overline{z^k}.$$ Now, $(\overline{z})^k,\overline{z}\in\Bbb R$ and $z^k,z\in\Bbb C$ and hence
$$(\overline{z})^{k+1}=(\overline{z})^k\cdot\overline{z}=\overline{z^k}\cdot\overline{z}\overbrace{=}^{\text{use the result}}\overline{z^kz}=\overline{z^{k+1}}.$$ Hence the statement also holds at $n=k+1$. The problem follows by induction.

Answer (score 0):

The base case is trivial $(\overline z=\overline z)$. Assume that $\overline z^k=\overline{z^k}$. Then

$$\overline z^{k+1}=\overline z^k\cdot \overline z=\overline{z^k}\cdot \overline z.$$

Now $z^k$ is some complex number $a+bi$ and $z$ is another complex number $c+di$.

$$\overline{z^k}\cdot\overline z=(a-bi)(c-di)=ac-bd-(ad+bc)i$$

and

$$\overline{z^{k+1}}=\overline{ac-bd+(ad+cb)i}$$